# Update total price based on radio input selection

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a table with 8 radio input buttons and I want to update the total price in the  based on the user's radio input selection. How to I achieve this by jQuery?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <form name="m" action="" method="post">
      <th> <input id="test" name="purchaseChoice" class="radio" onclick="togglePrices(false);" type="radio" value="P2"/>
        <label for="purchaseChoice">£5</span> </label>
        <input id="test" name="purchaseChoice" class="radio" onclick="togglePrices(true);" type="radio" value="P1"/>
        <label for="purchaseChoice">£10</label>
      </th>
      <th class=""> <input id="test" name="purchaseChoice" class="radio" onclick="togglePrices(true);" type="radio" value="S111"/>
        <label for="purchaseChoice">£20</label>
        <input id="test" name="purchaseChoice" class="radio" onclick="togglePrices(false);" type="radio" value="S112"/>
        <label for="purchaseChoice">£30</label>
      </th>
      <th class=""> <input id="test" name="purchaseChoice" class="radio" onclick="togglePrices(true);" type="radio" value="S131"/>
        <label for="purchaseChoice">£40</label>
        <input id="test" name="purchaseChoice" class="radio" onclick="togglePrices(false);" type="radio" value="S132"/>
        <label for="purchaseChoice">£50</label>
      </th>
      <th class="highlight"> <input id="test" name="purchaseChoice" class="radio" onclick="togglePrices(true);" type="radio" value="S121"/>
        <label for="purchaseChoice">£60</label>
        <input id="test" name="purchaseChoice" class="radio" onclick="togglePrices(false);" type="radio" value="S122"/>
        <label for="purchaseChoice">£70</label>
      </th>
    </form>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="total">TOTAL YOU PAY</th>
    <th> 
     <div class="Priceband"></div>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks

Comment: Price values are present in the input filed at the end. Basically, as you can see I have 8 values:  P1, P2, S112, S111, S121, S122, S131 and S132

Answer (score 0):

you should use `onselectionchanged` event to call the appropriate function that would update the total amount. you might look at the link below
http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/archive/index.php/t-10307334.html

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your requirement correctly than you just want to update price with selection changed.

please find the below code. might be helpful for you.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <form name="m" action="" method="post">
      <th> <input id="test" name="purchaseChoice" class="radio" onclick="togglePrices(this);" type="radio" value="P2"/>
        <label for="purchaseChoice">£5</span> </label>
        <input id="test" name="purchaseChoice" class="radio" onclick="togglePrices(this);" type="radio" value="P1"/>
        <label for="purchaseChoice">£10</label>
      </th>
      <th class=""> <input id="test" name="purchaseChoice" class="radio" onclick="togglePrices(this);" type="radio" value="S111"/>
        <label for="purchaseChoice">£20</label>
        <input id="test" name="purchaseChoice" class="radio" onclick="togglePrices(this);" type="radio" value="S112"/>
        <label for="purchaseChoice">£30</label>
      </th>
      <th class=""> <input id="test" name="purchaseChoice" class="radio" onclick="togglePrices(this);" type="radio" value="S131"/>
        <label for="purchaseChoice">£40</label>
        <input id="test" name="purchaseChoice" class="radio" onclick="togglePrices(this);" type="radio" value="S132"/>
        <label for="purchaseChoice">£50</label>
      </th>
      <th class="highlight"> <input id="test" name="purchaseChoice" class="radio" onclick="return togglePrices(this);" type="radio" value="S121"/>
        <label for="purchaseChoice">£60</label>
        <input id="test" name="purchaseChoice" class="radio" onclick="togglePrices(this);" type="radio" value="S122"/>
        <label for="purchaseChoice">£70</label>
      </th>
    </form>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="total">TOTAL YOU PAY</th>
    <th> 
     <div class="Priceband"></div>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >

    function togglePrices(e) {
        var price = $(e).val();
        $(".Priceband").html(price);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: I have tried that but I can't get any price showing in my "Priceband" div

Comment: I have tried the same code at my end. Its working fine for me. May be you are missing with Jquery references. Make sure to have reference of jquery library.

Comment: I have definately jQuery references as other jquery code on the page works fine. I have updated the code above for you to review again please. I found out some errors from what I first pasted in, maybe thats why is not working? Thanks so much for your help so far

Comment: I think that is working now. If I wanted to have a predefined default option on page load? what do I need to do? As an example, to preselect the expensive option from the two?

Comment: @george can you bit elaborate more?

Comment: What I meant was, when a user land on the page, I want the most expensive option to be checked as a default

Comment: Yes i got your point. We can do that too on pageload event. You just have to create a function and call it on page load event.Your logic should be placed on that function.